# Download image to server fetched by API

Tags: php

I use API from third party websites to make thumbnail images and show in my website. I use the following line in php to show the thumbnail image:

```
echo '<img src="http://api.thirdpartysite.org/?some_param" />';
```

it works fine and the image is shown perfectly in the browser. and of course from my browser I can save mage to my computer.

Is there a way I can directly download the image file directly to my server using php ?

edit:
I already tried

```
file_put_contents("image.png", fopen("http://api.thirdpartysite.org/?some_param'", 'r'));
```

and it creates an empty image file in the server

I am using shared hosting, linux server.

Comment: You have to use: `file_put_contents("image.png", file_get_contents("http://api.thirdpartysite.org/?some_param'"));`. The `fopen()` function can be a better way, but have a [different syntax](http://nl3.php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php).

Comment: thanks. it still creates an empty file, just with the watermark of the thirdparty site.

Comment: This is because third-part site probably doesn't allow direct download! This is complex question, depending of the third-part site, that check the `HTTP-REFERER`,  the cookies of something more complex.

Answer (score 0):

I used curl_exec()  and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

The great nuance is that you may not know the extension of downloaded image file. 
So currently I can suggest you a simple solution which will download the current google logo image (just for example).
 The list of functions we will use:
`file_get_contents`, `file_put_contents`, `getimagesize`, `rename`, `header`, `readfile`

```
$img = file_get_contents("https://www.google.com.ua/logos/doodles/2016/90th-anniversary-of-the-first-demonstration-of-television-6281357497991168.3-res.png");
file_put_contents("image", $img); // assuming that we don't know the extension at the moment
$image_data = getimagesize("image"); // getting image details
$ext = explode('/',$image_data['mime'])[1]; // getting image mime type
rename("image", "image." . $ext );  // rename image specifying determined extension 

// the immediate test: we will immediately output the downloaded image (just for testing) 
header("Content-Type: image/" . $ext);
readfile("image." . $ext);
```

And the output will be as shown below:
[image]